# Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins: maven-failsafe plugin:3.0.0-M5 integration-test A required class was missing(FaleSafeSummryXmlUtils)

Tags: junit4, maven-surefire-plugin, serenity-bdd, maven-failsafe-plugin

https://i.stack.imgur.com/fuFvg.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/CfQZE.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/HLTau.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/g1YrY.jpg

Jenkins build is failing due to this error. Could you please help here?

I tried changing maven surefire and maven failsafe version to 3.0.0 and junit as 4.13.2 but getting same error. Also tried mvn clean verify -U command.

Comment: Did you try to delete `.m2` folder and re-build project?